# Get access token for specific permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I modify this to get permissions for offline_access and others

"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id="+appId+"&client_secret=" + appSecret;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can.  The url you are using looks like the one used to get an access token for adminstrative actions on behalf of an **app**.  I.e. Graph api calls requiring an **app access token** such as access to app Insights.

Offline access, as far as I know, applies only to performing actions on behalf of a **user** e.g. posting to their wall.

Maybe you are looking for something more like this?

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?   client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=offline_access,email,read_stream,etc`

Assuming you have already know about the authentication guide, but just in case:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/